# Block Select in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS, how to enable block select (Alt + Shift)?

I think its enabled by default, but in my instance of SSMS, I am unable to do so.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 10.50.2500.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works on SQL 2012 and after. You are using SQL 2008.